# Retornar N elementos de uma lista no jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma lista de elementos, digamos uma lista de linhas de uma tabela:

```
$('#minha_tabela tr');
```

Há um seletor, método ou sobrecarga no jQuery que eu possa retornar mais de uma linha passando vários índices?

Algo como,

```
$('#minha_tabela tr').get(0, 2, 7);
```

Comment: Bom, o slice é sequencial, vc está dizendo uma lista arbitrária né? Vou ver se temos algo mais específico.

Comment: Humm, sim. A lista de índices poderia ser arbitrária. Mas isso eu posso contornar facilmente dando um `sort` nela antes de aplicar no método `slice`. Mas agradeceria se postasse algo com arbitrária :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se quer uma lista contínua, pode ser o `slice`:

Veja um exemplo:

```js
$('#tabela tr').slice( 2, 4 ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tabela">
  <tr><td>Linha 1</td><td>0001</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Linha 2</td><td>0002</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Linha 3</td><td>0003</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Linha 4</td><td>0004</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Linha 5</td><td>0005</td></tr>
</table>
```

Mas, se quer valores com uma sequência variada, pode usar um `.filter()` combinado com `.inArray()`:

```js
$('#tabela tr').filter( function( index ) {
   return $.inArray(index, [0,2,7]) >= 0;
} ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tabela">
  <tr><td>Linha  1</td><td>0001</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Linha  2</td><td>0002</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Linha  3</td><td>0003</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Linha  4</td><td>0004</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Linha  5</td><td>0005</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Linha  6</td><td>0006</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Linha  7</td><td>0007</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Linha  8</td><td>0008</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Linha  9</td><td>0009</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Linha 10</td><td>0010</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar vários seletores separando com vírgula e usar o `nth-child` para pegar um elemento específico. No caso do seu exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
// no nth-child, indices começam no um, não no zero
$('#minha_tabela tr:nth-child(1), #minha_tabela tr:nth-child(3), #minha_tabela tr:nth-child(8)');
```

Comment: Renato, os índices do array são dinâmicos (ok, eu tenho uma culpa por não explicar na pergunta). Embora, eu possa usar algo como `'[..]nth:child('+i+')[..]'`.